# How to define a list of files matching a pattern in CMake?

Tags: cmake

How can I define a variable in CMake containing a list of files that match a pattern? For instance, `test_*.cpp`?

And how can I define a variable containing a list of files that DON'T match a pattern? For instance, `test_*.cpp` should match all files EXCEPT those matched above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For matching the source files of a particular pattern , you can use globbing pattern.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST_FILES
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test_*.cpp"
)
```

I'm not sure of how to exclude those specific files, maybe excluding them from the list of all the files work , like this

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
)
list(REMOVE_ITEM ${SRC_FILES} ${TEST_FILES})
```

I was referring to `list REMOVE_ITEM` from this source http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/list.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your second example. `list(REMOVE_ITEM ${TEST_FILES})` should remove `TEST_FILES` from `SRC_FILES`? If so, shouldn't the variable `SRC_FILES` be mentioned somewhere in this command?

Comment: Maybe a typo, on my side the syntax I had to use to make it works is 'list(REMOVE_ITEM SRC_FILES ${TEST_FILES})' and not 'list(REMOVE_ITEM ${SRC_FILES} ${TEST_FILES})'.  My cmake version  is 3.9.5